# Bootstrap 3's 'img-responsive' - Can it have a max-width set to px?

Tags: image, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, max

Eg 256px?

I want images to change size but not any bigger than 256px.

I've googled this but for once come up with no solution.

Anyone know how to do this or another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the default bootstrap image responsiveness class to achieve this. Below is the code for the same.

```
.img-responsive, .thumbnail > img, .thumbnail a > img, .carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
     max-width: 256px;
}
```